# Error when trying to delete project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, workspace

I'm developing an Eclipse Plugin on Windows.

When trying to delete a project that was created with my plugin, **sometimes** I see the following error.

[image: error:]

When trying to debug my plugin at such a case, I see the following error:

> Error deleting resource '/ProjectName' from the workspace tree Could not
>   delete metadata for '/ProjectName'.

I couldn't find any file or stream that my plugin left open that may had caused this issue.

Anyone?

Comment: What does the 'Details' button show?

Comment: nothing much: "Could not delete /ProjectName/someFolder. Could not delete C:/users/user/workspace/ProjectName"

Comment: Is there any file left after the deletion failed in the folders that are left? Can you debug eclipse/your plugin to find the exact place in the code where the Exception occurs? The error message is pretty generic.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message there.

Comment: looking at that .log file, i can see that it always fails due to the same file.
That file is edited by the plugin with a BufferedWriter, the plugin calls BufferedWriter.close() when it finishes with the edit, could it be that it takes  time until the handle to the file is actually closed? (waiting a while and then trying to delete - succeeds), or perhaps is there anther additional step the plugin must do to release that file?